# My have a button with a popover that works fine on preview. When testing it on IOS device, can only click the button once then it is stuck

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am currently learning swift and want to create a button with a popover view to display some info. On the content preivew, it works just fine but when downloading to my iPhone, if I click the button once it works. After that, the button is broken and popover doesn't show. Almost like a dead button

```
var body: some View {
   @State var showHelp = false
    NavigationView {
        List {
        //logic stuff
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button("Help") {
                showHelp = true
            }
            .popover(isPresented: $showHelp) {
                Text("Foobar")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this approach, moving `@State var showHelp = false` outside the `body`. Here is a working example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showHelp = false  // <-- here

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                //logic stuff
                Text("the list")
            }
            .toolbar {
                Button("Help") {
                    showHelp = true
                }
            }
        }
        .popover(isPresented: $showHelp) {  // <-- here
            Text("Foobar")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

See also: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state   and  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-user-interface-state

Note, `NavigationView` is deprecated, use `NavigationStack` instead.